# Incorrect reference PcapDotNet.?.dll

Tags: visual-studio, reference, winpcap, pcap, pcap.net

Hello
I try to use PcapDotNet dll but I can't add reference to my project.
It doesn't matter which dll it is. PcapDotNet.Core.dll, PcapDotNet.Base.dll etc.
I have yellow exclamation mark near this reference and can't use any methods from this dll.
Ofc "using PcapDotNet.Core;" is underlined too and compiler shows me: "The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the namespace 'PcapDotNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"
Different dll I can add normally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rubbed my crystal ball and it said: "you downloaded this from the Codeplex site and you are using a Visual Studio edition earlier than 2010."

It's usually pretty reliable when it gets that explicit, I'll work from the assumption that it is accurate.  If you are not ready to upgrade to VS2010 then you'll need the 0.6.0 version, as documented on the [landing page](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/46580).  The 0.6.0 download is listed in the upper right box, this is [the link](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/44962).

Comment: Yeah :) crystal ball works great :) Time for VS2010 coming soon, but now ver 0.6.0. is sufficient :) Thanks